# matlab - ith element of vector is the sum of the first i elements of a different vector

Tags: matlab, sum

I'm trying to compute a vector A for which the ith element is the sum of the first i elements of a different vector B (this vector is given).

I couldn't work out how to do this and the internet wasn't much help either.
I am very new to matlab so an easy solution would be preferred :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use MATLAB's cumsum function.
code example:

```
%generates random vector b
b = rand(5,1);
%calculates accomulative sum
a = cumsum(b);
```

Result:

```
b = [0.4319    0.9616    0.5671    0.8731    0.5730]
a = [0.4319    1.3935    1.9606    2.8338    3.4068]
```